# How to setting up EditBox

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editbox, liclipse

Im trying to set up EditBox in LiClipse for python but nothing I do makes it work. I feel like I've tried everything but maybe I missed something. Can anyone who was able to set it up explain how they did it?

[I'm trying to get it to look like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xHHK.png)

Comment: What exactly do you want in EditBox? (if it's just vertical indent guides, you can enable the option in the preferences > PyDev > Editor > Vertical Indent Guides)

Comment: No, I'm trying to get the code blocks to be highlighted similar to how BlueJay looks, and how EditBox displays on their github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some messing around and I found the answer! You need to select the category to the right that is associated with your language (or whatever category you want to store the layout in) and press the add button on the bottom left to add the file type. Simply type in your file type (for example if using the language C in script Test.c type *.c) and press OK, then from there your all set! You can customize the format in the categories tabs above to make yours look unique or more suited for your needs. Hope this helped anyone else confused about setting up EditBox :)

[Image of solution:<- Click b/c I cant post pictures yet lol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yz5T1.png)

[My Suggestion For a Good Configuration (Using LiClipse Dark Theme): <- Click Me :D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nPar.png)